# Laravel Nova how to create custom filters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

When I try to do `PHP artisan nova:filter MyNewFilter` the terminal gives me the message that the filter has been created, but I can't find it anywhere, even though after reading the [Laravel Nova Docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/filters/defining-filters.html#defining-filters) where it says `By default, Nova will place newly generated filters in the app/Nova/Filters directory` the folder is never generated. Am I missing something here?

Please help...

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at app/Nova directory and not Nova directory?

Answer (score 0):

The filter should be created under the root of your application in `nova-components/MyNewFilter` folder.